# Null value being returned from view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a view model (IntakeSampleViewModel) that contains an EF6 entity (Intake) among other properties.  This pattern has worked very well in the past.  Eliminate copying data from one class to another class when moving data in or out of the database.

```
public IntakeSampleViewModel()
      {
         myIntake = new Intake();
         myRequests = new List<int>();
      }
```

In this case it works when I am creating a new Intake object.  The method signature looks like this.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(IntakeSampleViewModel inModel)
```

And inside this method I have this line

```
cldb.Intakes.Add(inModel.myIntake);
```

And all works out great.
Except for when I want to edit.  Here is the method signature.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(IntakeSampleViewModel inModel)
```

The first thing I try to do is this. And I get an error stating that myIntake is null.  And when debugging it is indeed null.

```
cldb.Intakes.Attach(inModel.myIntake);
```

Inside my edit view page I have this line.

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.myIntake)
```

I put together a small test in Java script to test for null, but it returns false.

```
TEST = function () {
    var temp = $('#myIntake').val();
    alert(temp === null);
}
```

So I believe myIntake is not null in the view page, but for some reason it is not being ‘attached’ to the IntakeSampleViewModel on the submit.  Can anybody suggest something to try?
Cheers
bob

Comment: InTake seems to be a class in your ViewModel. Not sure if that is your goal or if you want to return a specific value from the class? open the console in your browser, add a breakpoint to the jQuery and check if #myIntake has any data in it.

Comment: Yes InTake is a full class and that is what I wanted.  Not positive it is a good idea, just something I started doing a while ago.  There is a value for InTake, but I can not seem to get any values for the properties of the InTake class.

Comment: I suggest checking if your GET method is sending data to the view. When you do $('#myIntake').val(); it basically would be checking if the object exists(which it does since you initialize it in the model) which might still be empty. Try instantiating myIntake as 
public Intake myIntake {get;set;}

Comment: both of your methods are post and just the name changes, so I think your error is when sending data

Comment: Apart from the fact that you need public properties, you cannot bind a complex to a hidden input - you need an input for each property of `Intake` (but it would be crazy to do that if you not editing the `Intake` - if you need it in the post method for some reason, you just get it again)

Comment: Stephen, I think you hit it on the head with binding a complex to a hidden input.  That explains to me why it worked on the create method and not on the edit method.  Thanks very much.